# Parsing JSON with AJAX/Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html

My Code so far looks like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=world%20&api-key=4dftzq5rzqbkc7h3b3epsgem",
      dataType: "JSON",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
});
```

I do not know now how to call the actual content from the api. 
The JSON looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FvgL.jpg

Comment: Your code is working: `data.response` in your success callback yields the requested data.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling to the api, when the document is ready.

You can fill a list with the current results from the response, by accessing `data.response.results`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=world%20&api-key=4dftzq5rzqbkc7h3b3epsgem",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.response.results.length; i++) {
        $("#results").append("<li>" + data.response.results[i].webTitle + "</li>");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="results">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! however when i put that exact code into my code, it still doesnt show up in my site

Comment: Are you getting errors in the Google Chrome console?

Comment: it is working now thanks!! I was also wondering, is there a way to get the pictures from each article to show?

Comment: Hmm, with your actual json data, you can't get the pictures from each article.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `dataType: "json"` it evaluates the response as **JSON** and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=world%20&api-key=4dftzq5rzqbkc7h3b3epsgem",
     dataType: "JSON",
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data); //already parsed object
       console.log(data.response); //try accessing your property.
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what do want to archive?, data should be an object that already contains everything you need. You could now do something like: 
    data.response.results[0].webTitle